# SQL Server - Same query, same database, different results

Tags: sql-server, locking, isolation-level

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 with 2 tables. I'm running the following query on Management Studio:

```
select M.FD_BROWSER_SHORT_NAME AS X, Count(1) AS Y
from TB_EVENTS E 
     INNER JOIN TB_MACHINES M ON E.FD_ID = M.FD_ID AND E.FD_ID_NET = M.FD_ID_NET
where E.FD_EVENT_CODE = 30        
group by M.FD_BROWSER_SHORT_NAME
having Count(1) > 10
```

When I run this query, the results are:

```
X    Y
OP   23
CR   1809
IE   5392
MZ   1000
```

Then I run the query again (F5), on the same database (same session). The result changes to:

```
X    Y
OP   1023
CR   1809
IE   5392
```

When I run the query again the result back to normal:

```
X    Y
OP   23
CR   1809
IE   5392
MZ   1000
```

On the same server, at same time, I have a C# application changing the database (INSERTs and UPDATEs). When I stop this application, the problem stops.

First, I thought the problem was related to locks. Then I tried to add this before the SQL statement:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

But the problem keeps ocurring.

I tried to reproduce the problem in another server, but it don't occurs. I tried to migrated the database to another server and another version of SQL Server and it still occurs.

The problem occurs with another queries containing aggregation functions.

I also tried to update the statistics and rebuild all the indexes. Nothing...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your C# app is locking before you can set transaction. 
Try read uncommitted and see what is shown:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```